# Not sure what apps to include in Heroku/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Ok, so I'm continuing a project that was worked on by someone else and am having trouble getting started. Most of the webpages work, but this one fails to load and gives the "sorry, but something went wrong heroku error." Edited to show logs instead:

```
2013-07-13T22:48:54.242683+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
2013-07-13T22:49:24.652125+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/" for 184.73.237.85 at 2013-07-13 22:49:24 +0000
2013-07-13T22:49:24.657848+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as */*
2013-07-13T22:49:24.657848+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
2013-07-13T22:49:24.659765+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/users/ host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="184.73.237.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=302 bytes=0
2013-07-13T22:49:36.267545+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
2013-07-13T22:49:36.271518+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/users/ host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=302 bytes=0
2013-07-13T22:49:36.267545+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as */*
2013-07-13T22:49:36.263202+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/" for 50.112.95.211 at 2013-07-13 22:49:36 +0000
2013-07-13T22:50:22.797779+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/users/ host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="204.93.223.151" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=12ms status=302 bytes=0
2013-07-13T22:50:22.793360+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as */*
2013-07-13T22:50:22.789286+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/" for 204.93.223.151 at 2013-07-13 22:50:22 +0000
2013-07-13T22:50:22.793360+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
2013-07-13T22:50:32.854645+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.253.43.209 at 2013-07-13 22:50:32 +0000
2013-07-13T22:50:32.862423+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="69.253.43.209" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=11ms status=302 bytes=109
2013-07-13T22:50:32.859366+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
2013-07-13T22:50:32.859366+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
2013-07-13T22:50:32.771775+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H16 desc="herokuapp redirect" method=GET path=/ host=statitup.heroku.com fwd="69.253.43.209" dyno= connect= service= status=301 bytes=
2013-07-13T22:50:32.918512+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 69.253.43.209 at 2013-07-13 22:50:32 +0000
2013-07-13T22:50:32.939617+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 14.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2013-07-13T22:50:32.939617+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
2013-07-13T22:50:32.939617+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.8ms)
2013-07-13T22:50:32.939617+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
2013-07-13T22:50:32.952994+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/sign_in host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="69.253.43.209" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=38ms status=200 bytes=10410
2013-07-13T22:50:33.007693+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-fd933ac454d6a0ea35b3b5adcd6f1204.css host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="69.253.43.209" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=280630
2013-07-13T22:50:33.089756+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-8ba7ca1fe7c19bd934c2b34512260f28.js host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="69.253.43.209" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=347056
2013-07-13T22:50:35.909701+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="69.253.43.209" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-07-13T22:50:41.924753+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 69.253.43.209 at 2013-07-13 22:50:41 +0000
2013-07-13T22:50:42.097659+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
2013-07-13T22:50:42.097659+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 167ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2013-07-13T22:50:42.097659+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"email"=>"aschade@sas.upenn.edu", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
2013-07-13T22:50:42.097659+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://statitup.herokuapp.com/
2013-07-13T22:50:42.100695+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/users/sign_in host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="69.253.43.209" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=226ms status=302 bytes=96
2013-07-13T22:50:42.161920+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 69.253.43.209 at 2013-07-13 22:50:42 +0000
2013-07-13T22:50:42.179589+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (6.3ms)
2013-07-13T22:50:42.179589+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
2013-07-13T22:50:42.179589+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 6.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)
2013-07-13T22:50:42.179589+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
2013-07-13T22:50:42.184202+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="69.253.43.209" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=27ms status=200 bytes=5562
2013-07-13T22:50:43.778972+00:00 app[web.1]:     79:         'start': new Date(<%= @bp.first.created_at.strftime("%Y") %>, (<%= @bp.first.created_at.strftime("%m") %> - 1), <%= @bp.first.created_at.strftime("%e") %>, <%= @bp.first.created_at.strftime("%k") %>, <%= @bp.first.created_at.strftime("%M") %>, <%= @bp.first.created_at.strftime("%S") %>),
2013-07-13T22:50:43.778972+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-07-13T22:50:43.779152+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/stats_controller.rb:46:in `index'
2013-07-13T22:50:43.779339+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered stats/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
2013-07-13T22:50:43.778972+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `created_at' for nil:NilClass):
2013-07-13T22:50:43.778972+00:00 app[web.1]:     81:       //'state': {'range': {'start': first, 'end': last}}
2013-07-13T22:50:43.779339+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StatsController#index as HTML
2013-07-13T22:50:43.762823+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/stats" for 69.253.43.209 at 2013-07-13 22:50:43 +0000
2013-07-13T22:50:43.778972+00:00 app[web.1]:     76:       // Initial range: 2012-02-09 to 2012-03-20.
2013-07-13T22:50:43.779152+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-07-13T22:50:43.778972+00:00 app[web.1]:     78:       'state': {'range': {
2013-07-13T22:50:43.779152+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-07-13T22:50:43.778972+00:00 app[web.1]:     80:         'end': new Date(<%= @bp.last.created_at.strftime("%Y") %>, (<%= @bp.last.created_at.strftime("%m") %> - 1), <%= @bp.last.created_at.strftime("%e") %>, <%= @bp.last.created_at.strftime("%k") %>, <%= @bp.last.created_at.strftime("%M") %>, <%= @bp.last.created_at.strftime("%S") %>)}}
2013-07-13T22:50:43.778972+00:00 app[web.1]:     82:     });
2013-07-13T22:50:43.778972+00:00 app[web.1]:     77:       //'state': {'range': {'start': new Date(2013, 0, 1), 'end': new Date(2013, 4, 2)}}
2013-07-13T22:50:43.779339+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms
2013-07-13T22:50:43.778972+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/stats/index.html.erb:79:in `_app_views_stats_index_html_erb__2767662790772891844_35763980'
2013-07-13T22:50:43.820606+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/stats host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="69.253.43.209" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=61ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-07-13T22:50:54.241260+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/" for 50.18.57.7 at 2013-07-13 22:50:54 +0000
2013-07-13T22:50:54.246383+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as */*
2013-07-13T22:50:54.246383+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
2013-07-13T22:50:54.251869+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/users/ host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="50.18.57.7" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=302 bytes=0
2013-07-13T22:51:24.550342+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/" for 184.73.237.85 at 2013-07-13 22:51:24 +0000
2013-07-13T22:51:24.555773+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/users/ host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="184.73.237.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=302 bytes=0
2013-07-13T22:51:24.554278+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as */*
2013-07-13T22:51:24.554278+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
2013-07-13T22:51:36.273183+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/" for 50.112.95.211 at 2013-07-13 22:51:36 +0000
2013-07-13T22:51:36.279094+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
2013-07-13T22:51:36.279094+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as */*
2013-07-13T22:51:36.282064+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/users/ host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=302 bytes=0
2013-07-13T22:52:22.305998+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/" for 204.93.223.151 at 2013-07-13 22:52:22 +0000
2013-07-13T22:52:22.309953+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as */*
2013-07-13T22:52:22.309953+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
2013-07-13T22:52:22.313327+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/users/ host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="204.93.223.151" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=11ms status=302 bytes=0
2013-07-13T22:52:54.257302+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as */*
2013-07-13T22:52:54.259081+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/users/ host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="50.18.57.7" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=302 bytes=0
2013-07-13T22:52:54.257302+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
2013-07-13T22:52:54.252167+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/" for 50.18.57.7 at 2013-07-13 22:52:54 +0000
2013-07-13T22:53:24.645611+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/" for 184.73.237.85 at 2013-07-13 22:53:24 +0000
2013-07-13T22:53:24.661404+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
2013-07-13T22:53:24.661404+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as */*
2013-07-13T22:53:24.674506+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/users/ host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="184.73.237.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=31ms status=302 bytes=0
2013-07-13T22:53:36.266076+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/" for 50.112.95.211 at 2013-07-13 22:53:36 +0000
2013-07-13T22:53:36.281406+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/users/ host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=302 bytes=0
2013-07-13T22:53:36.278796+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as */*
2013-07-13T22:53:36.278796+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
2013-07-13T22:54:22.349939+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/" for 204.93.223.151 at 2013-07-13 22:54:22 +0000
2013-07-13T22:54:22.359597+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/users/ host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="204.93.223.151" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=15ms status=302 bytes=0
2013-07-13T22:54:22.356103+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
2013-07-13T22:54:22.356103+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as */*
2013-07-13T22:54:54.298559+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/" for 50.18.57.7 at 2013-07-13 22:54:54 +0000
2013-07-13T22:54:54.305714+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
2013-07-13T22:54:54.305714+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as */*
2013-07-13T22:54:54.312984+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/users/ host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="50.18.57.7" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=17ms status=302 bytes=0
2013-07-13T22:55:25.025850+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/" for 184.73.237.85 at 2013-07-13 22:55:25 +0000
2013-07-13T22:55:25.030908+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as */*
2013-07-13T22:55:25.030908+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
2013-07-13T22:55:25.033020+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/users/ host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="184.73.237.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=302 bytes=0
2013-07-13T22:55:36.280634+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/" for 50.112.95.211 at 2013-07-13 22:55:36 +0000
2013-07-13T22:55:36.284696+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms
2013-07-13T22:55:36.284696+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#index as */*
2013-07-13T22:55:36.284054+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path=/users/ host=statitup.herokuapp.com fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=19ms status=302 bytes=0
```

So obviously the person that was working on this before me is using some google package to display graphs on the webpage. Is the issue that I don't have an add-on included on Heroku? Does anyone know what that app might be? Am I missing a gem? Sorry if this is a total noob question, but I've been wasting a lot of time figuring it out and I think that the answer probably isn't too complicated.

Comment: Looking it at your logs it says undefined method 'created_at' for nil:NilClass.
It looks like @bp.last is turning out to to be nil and hence causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

The code is related to Google Charts, and since it is JavaScript based, it gets downloaded from Google's sites at the runtime in user's browser.  So, it is highly likely that you are not missing any "gem", unless you can point to some errors that you are seeing that indicates otherwise.

Also, check the [heroku logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval) using:

```
heroku logs
```

Comment: I edited the post to show my logs, but in general what should I be looking for?

Comment: 2013-07-13T22:50:43.778972+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `created_at' for nil:NilClass):
2013-07-13T22:50:43.778972+00:00 app[web.1]:     81:       //'state': {'range': {'start': first, 'end': last}}
2013-07-13T22:50:43.779339+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StatsController#index as HTML

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Wand Maker's post, you can go into the terminal and run

```
heroku logs -t -n 100
```

This command runs trailing logs, meaning that the latest 100 (or however many you specify) will be automatically updated to your terminal, allowing you to run even more comprehensive tests.

Also, if you could remove that lengthy JS and instead show us your heroku logs, that would be much better.